# How to filter a collection by multiple conditions

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file named film.csv here is the header line with a few lines to use as an example

```
Year;Length;Title;Subject;Actor;Actress;Director;Popularity;Awards;*Image
1990;111;Tie Me Up! Tie Me Down!;Comedy;Banderas, Antonio;Abril, Victoria;Almodóvar, Pedro;68;No;NicholasCage.png
1991;113;High Heels;Comedy;Bosé, Miguel;Abril, Victoria;Almodóvar, Pedro;68;No;NicholasCage.png
1983;104;Dead Zone, The;Horror;Walken, Christopher;Adams, Brooke;Cronenberg, David;79;No;NicholasCage.png
1979;122;Cuba;Action;Connery, Sean;Adams, Brooke;Lester, Richard;6;No;seanConnery.png
1978;94;Days of Heaven;Drama;Gere, Richard;Adams, Brooke;Malick, Terrence;14;No;NicholasCage.png
1983;140;Octopussy;Action;Moore, Roger;Adams, Maud;Glen, John;68;No;NicholasCage.png
```

I am trying to filter, and need to display the move titles, for this criteria: first name contains "Richard", Year < 1985, Awards == "Y"

I am able to filter for the award, but not the rest. can you help?

```
file_name = "film.csv"
lines = (line for line in open(file_name,encoding='cp1252')) #generator to capture lines
lists = (s.rstrip().split(";") for s in lines) #generators to capture lists containing values from lines

#browse lists and index them per header values, then filter all movies that have been awarded
#using a new generator object

cols=next(lists) #obtains only the header
print(cols)
collections = (dict(zip(cols,data)) for data in lists)
    
filtered = (col["Title"] for col in collections if col["Awards"][0] == "Y")
                                                
                                                 
                                                       
for item in filtered:
        print(item)
    #   input()
```

This works for the award but I don't know how to add additional filters. Also when I try to filter for `if col["Year"] < 1985` I get error message because string vs  int not compatible. How do I make the years a value?
I believe for the first name I can filter like this:
`if col["Actor"].split(", ")[-1] == "Richard"`

Comment: You need to look into pandas

Comment: @Chris A beginner shouldn't add complexity by working with sophisticated external libraries.

Comment: pandas is good for this, but you can do it with pure python. I'd suggest looking into [`csv module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) in the standard library

Comment: @Tristan the data is missing the 4th row has less values

Comment: To convert a string to an integer, use "int", here `int(col["Year"]) < 1985`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know how to add one filter. There is no such thing as "additional" filters. Just add your conditions to the current condition. Since you want *all* of the conditions to be `True` to select a record, you'd use the boolean *and* logic. For example:

```
filtered = (
             col["Title"] 
             for col in collections 
             if col["Awards"][0] == "Y"
            and col["Actor"].split(", ")[-1] == "Richard"
            and int(col["Year"]) < 1985
           )
```

Notice I added an `int()` around the `col["Year"]` to convert it to an integer.

---

You've actually gone and reinvented `csv.DictReader` in the setup to this problem! Instead of

```
file_name = "film.csv"
lines = (line for line in open(file_name,encoding='cp1252')) #generator to capture lines
lists = (s.rstrip().split(";") for s in lines) #generators to capture lists containing values from lines

#browse lists and index them per header values, then filter all movies that have been awarded
#using a new generator object

cols=next(lists) #obtains only the header
print(cols)
collections = (dict(zip(cols,data)) for data in lists)
filtered = ...
```

You could have just done:

```
import csv

file_name = "film.csv"
with open(file_name) as f:
    collections = csv.DictReader(delimiter=";")
    filtered = ...
```